# unicode to binary?

Tags: javascript, unicode, binary, type-conversion

In Javascript, how can I convert BMP unicode characters to binary (and back)?

I can't seem to find any built-in string method `binaryCharCodeAt()` does something like that exist?

If not, my guess as to how to do it manually would be to create an array containing for example `[00001111], [00001110], [00001100]` and so on...

Then to get binary, I could do `myArray[String.charCodeAt(j)]`

Then to go from binary to unicode, I could search the array for a binary string, returning its position in the array, and put that into `String.fromCharCode()`

In this case, these binary codes are arbitrarily assigned, and arent the correct ones for each character. But thats ok.. (although correct would be preferred) I just need any binary.

The problem I foresee is, to search an array containing 65000+ items, hundreds or thousands of times, could end up costing a lot of processing time.

So, is there any pre-existing method or library, or can you suggest a better way to do this manually?

Comment: what do you mean by BMP unicode characters?

Comment: @Esailija, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane

Comment: And what's wrong with `String.fromCharCode( "a".charCodeAt(0) )`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do note that it is not totally correct to say "to binary and back", because unicode characters do not need to have a unique binary representation (it depends on the encoding, e.g. UTF-8). However I believe most of the UTF-... encodings are backwards-compatible with each other in terms of binary encodings.

But since you stated that you don't care what encoding you are using, you can do exactly as Kolink said (his answer was improperly downvoted, but was also not complete):

*edit:* As Esailija points out, the OP was only interested in basic multilingual plane characters, which only have one codepoint. The below code is overkill, though will still work on both BMP and non-BMP codepoints.

`"some string".charCodeAt` gives you the hex of the codepoints of some encoding. In my case it is UTF-16:

```
"".charCodeAt(0)==55356
"".charCodeAt(1)==56513
```

In UTF-16 this is `0xF0 0x9F 0x83 0x81` (`f09f8381`), or "\uD83C\uDCC1":

```
"\uD83C\uDCC1"==""
```

You cannot just assume that charCodeAt will give you the number you want without some amount of work. Unicode is a variable-width encoding. Therefore you can do the following to get a self-consistent result.

```
var UTF_BITS = 16;

function padLeftTo(string, padChar, numChars) {
    return (new Array(numChars-string.length+1)).join(padChar) + string;
}

function unicodeToBinary(char) {
    return char.split('').map(function(codepoint) {
        return padLeftTo(codepoint.charCodeAt(0).toString(2), 0, UTF_BITS);
    }).join('').split('').map(function(char){return parseInt(char)});
    //         ^^^^( ignore this part if you just want a string )^^^^
}

function binaryToUnicode(binaryList) {
    var codepointsAsNumbers = [];
    while( binaryList.length>0 ){
        var codepointBits = binaryList.slice(0,UTF_BITS);
        binaryList = binaryList.slice(UTF_BITS);
        codepointsAsNumbers.push( parseInt(codepointBits.join(''),2) );
    }
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(this,codepointsAsNumbers);
}
```

Demo:

```
> unicodeToBinary("")
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

> binaryToUnicode(unicodeToBinary(""))
""
```

Do note that since you didn't say what your use-case was, binary might not be really what you want. For example if you are content with unique identifiers, you could use the strings themselves, or hex-string or even integer representations. It is much more likely you want a simpler representation.

complete sidenote: If you are planning to use an object as a lookup table, you can just use the original original string "" as the key, e.g. `table={}; table[""]='something'; table[""]`. However because there are 95156 characters in the unicode 3.2 standard, I would not suggest doing any such thing in memory. You also said something which made me think you were not familiar with the performance of a lookup table: in case you were not aware, it takes O(1) time to do `table[...]`.

Comment: The BMP characters are always gotten in a single `.charCodeAt`. Javascript uses UTF-16 (or UCS2) by specification. You can verify this by running `var l = 0x10000;

while( l-- ) {
 console.log( String.fromCharCode(l).charCodeAt(0) === l );
}`

Comment: @Esailija: ah, silly me, thank you. I forgot he was asking about the BMP. I will leave a note.

Comment: as a sidenote I still have no idea what the op is asking but this seems to be the best answer so far so +1 :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `charCodeAt` to get the decimal number, then call `toString(2)` on it to convert it to binary.

Comment: That's not binary it's a string. A byte represented in `.toString(2)` form takes 16 bytes of memory and needs string manipulation to handle... one couldn't be more ineffective even if he tried.

Comment: @Esailija: that is an improper reason to downvote, and string manipulation seems perfectly reasonable in this context.

Comment: @ninjagecko The OP's worry about taking a lot of processing time would actually only apply if you were to use string manipulation and representation (For example, representing `0xFF` as a string `"11111111"`). If he didn't mention this in his post you would probably be right.

Comment: @Esailija: I believe what the author was mentioning was predicated on the hypothetical example of a table-lookup approach. I doubt he was actually needing to construct such an array or lookup table as part of his application logic.